# android WebView OnPageFinished error sometimes..when call loadURL()

Tags: android, css, memory, webview, call

my first question!

simply Sometimes OnPageFinished() didnt works when call loadURL()

my app is call loadURL() automatically periodically 
like a Asite -> Bsite-> Csite -> Dsite -> Esite

the problem is ...
when i use onPageFinished() to know that page loading is done.....
onPageFinished() is not working sometimes

process is just like

Asite ->onPageFinished-> Bsite ->onPageFinished->
Csite ->onPageFinished-> Dsite ->onPageFinished-> Esite

webview call loadURL() to A->B->C->D->E in very short time!!!!!!

i also cheaked memory leaking, destroing webview..but i cant solve the problem

is anybody here to solve my problem???

Comment: try using onLoadResource

Comment: tnk but i tried the method too......

Comment: insert logs on onLoadResource

Comment: onLoadResource doesnt wait for loading page..if i use the method it call loadURL() to A->B->C->D->E in very short time

Comment: yup you could only see what url is parsed in webview

Answer (score 0):

I do not know yet but the snippet below is the simplest way, according to me, to fire onPageFinished callback method.

webView.loadUrl(baseUrl, null)